# excel vba use command if

Tags: vba, excel

I have two excel files (file 1 with sheet 1 and file 2 with sheet 2).
Both have inside, in column A all the names (for example in A1: "a", in A2: "b" etc etc), in column B the values of relative lenghts (for example in B1: "2", in B2: "3" etc etc) but the orders of the things in the two sheets are different; so, I would want to say: "if the name in a cell in column A of sheet 1 is the same of the name in a cell in column A of sheet 2, so compare the relative values in column B and write TRUE in column C of one of the sheet (if the values are identical) or FALSE"
for you is possible? could you help me, please?
thanks in advance

Comment: If one of these answers was a solution for you, please accept it.  Otherwise, please explain what is still lacking in the answers.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If Sheet1 has

```
a    5
b    6
c    7
d    8
```

and Sheet2 has

```
c    3
d    8
a    5
```

then you can type

```
=IFERROR(IF(B1=INDIRECT("Sheet2!B"&MATCH(A1,Sheet2!A$1:A$4,0)),"Match Found",""),"")
```

into cell C1 of Sheet1 and drag the fill handle down and you will get

```
Match Found


Match Found
```

in column C of Sheet1.  No VBA needed.  :)

Note: Since your second sheet is actually in a separate file, you'll want to change `Sheet2` to `[file2.xlsx]Sheet1` in cell C1.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid `INDIRECT` function then try the following:

Assuming your `Sheet1` of `file1` is as follows:

[image]

And `Sheet2` of another file is like:

[image]

Enter the following formula in `Cell C1` of `Sheet2' and drag/copy it down as required.

```
=IFERROR(IF(B1=INDEX([file1.xlsx]Sheet1!$B$1:$B$5,MATCH(A1,[file1.xlsx]Sheet1!$A$1:$A$5,0)),TRUE),FALSE)
```

Comment: with your formula excel say to me that there is a problem with =

Comment: @Max - Not sure why its giving you error, its a tested and working formula. Can you please share exact error message you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

I would want to copy the word TRUE, only if I compare the same cell of the two sheets and I find that only a part of the name of that cell is the same ( because in reality in cell there is not only a, b, c but a sentence for example as "Sample 1 SX arrow" and others as "Sample 1 DX arrow") and so I want to put in column C the word TRUE only if not complete name in column A are the same but only part of the sentence ( for ecample only the part "SX arrow"!!!
How can I add this in the loop ?

Comment: Your requirement explained here and the one in the question are different. It will be better if you can provide your data and desired result.